# How can I generate a financial summary using pandas dataframes?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, summary

I'd like to create a table from a data frame with subtotals per business, totals per business type, and columns summing multiple value columns. Long term is to create a selection tool based on the ingested Excel sheet for whichever month's summary I bring in to compare month summaries (e.g. did minerals item 26 from BA3 disappear the next month) but I believe that is best saved for another question.

For now, I am having trouble figuring out how to summarize the data.

I have a dataframe in Pandas that contains the following:

```
Business | Business Type | ID | Value-Q1 | Value-Q2 | Value-Q3 | Value-Q4 | Value-FY |
---------+---------------+----+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
BA1      | Widgets       | 1  | 7        | 0        | 0        | 8        | 15       |
BA1      | Widgets       | 2  | 7        | 0        | 0        | 8        | 15       |
BA1      | Cups          | 3  | 9        | 10       | 0        | 0        | 19       |
BA1      | Cups          | 4  | 9        | 10       | 0        | 0        | 19       |
BA1      | Cups          | 5  | 9        | 10       | 0        | 0        | 19       |
BA1      | Snorkels      | 6  | 0        | 0        | 8        | 8        | 16       |
BA1      | Snorkels      | 7  | 0        | 0        | 8        | 8        | 16       |
BA1      | Snorkels      | 8  | 0        | 0        | 8        | 8        | 16       |
BA2      | Widgets       | 9  | 100      | 0        | 7        | 0        | 107      |
BA2      | Widgets       | 10 | 100      | 0        | 7        | 0        | 107      |
BA2      | Widgets       | 11 | 100      | 0        | 7        | 0        | 107      |
BA2      | Widgets       | 12 | 100      | 0        | 7        | 0        | 107      |
BA2      | Bread         | 13 | 0        | 0        | 0        | 1        | 1        |
BA2      | Bread         | 14 | 0        | 0        | 0        | 1        | 1        |
BA2      | Bread         | 15 | 0        | 0        | 0        | 1        | 1        |
BA2      | Bread         | 16 | 0        | 0        | 0        | 1        | 1        |
BA2      | Cat Food      | 17 | 504      | 0        | 0        | 500      | 1004     |
BA2      | Cat Food      | 18 | 504      | 0        | 0        | 500      | 1004     |
BA2      | Cat Food      | 19 | 504      | 0        | 0        | 500      | 1004     |
BA2      | Cat Food      | 20 | 504      | 0        | 0        | 500      | 1004     |
BA2      | Cat Food      | 21 | 504      | 0        | 0        | 500      | 1004     |
BA3      | Gravel        | 22 | 7        | 7        | 7        | 7        | 28       |
BA3      | Gravel        | 23 | 7        | 7        | 7        | 7        | 28       |
BA3      | Gravel        | 24 | 7        | 7        | 7        | 7        | 28       |
BA3      | Rocks         | 25 | 3        | 2        | 0        | 0        | 5        |
BA3      | Minerals      | 26 | 1        | 1        | 0        | 1        | 3        |
BA3      | Minerals      | 27 | 1        | 1        | 0        | 1        | 3        |
BA4      | Widgets       | 28 | 6        | 4        | 0        | 0        | 10       |
BA4      | Widgets       | 29 | 6        | 4        | 0        | 0        | 10       |
BA4      | Widgets       | 30 | 6        | 4        | 0        | 0        | 10       |
BA4      | Widgets       | 31 | 6        | 4        | 0        | 0        | 10       |
BA4      | Widgets       | 32 | 6        | 4        | 0        | 0        | 10       |
BA4      | Something     | 33 | 1000     | 0        | 0        | 2        | 1002     |
BA5      | Bonbons       | 34 | 60       | 40       | 10       | 0        | 110      |
BA5      | Bonbons       | 35 | 60       | 40       | 10       | 0        | 110      |
BA5      | Gummy Bears   | 36 | 7        | 0        | 0        | 9        | 16       |
```

(Imagine each ID has different values as well)

My goal is to slice the data to get the total occurrences of a given business type (e.g. BA 1 has 2 widgets, 3 cups, and 3 snorkels which each have a unique ID) as well as the total values:

```
                Occurrence | Q1 Sum | Q2 Sum | Q3 Sum | Q4 Sum | FY Sum |

BA 1            8          | 41     | 30     | 24     | 40     | 135    |

   Widgets      2          | 14     | 0      | 0      | 16     | 30     |
   Cups         3          | 27     | 30     | 0      | 0      | 57     |
   Snorkels     3          | 0      | 0      | 24     | 24     | 48     |

BA 2           Subtotal of BA2 items below

   Widgets     Repeat Above
   Bread       Repeat Above
   Cat Food    Repeat Above
```

I have more columns that mirror the Q1-FY columns with other fields (e.g. Value 2 Q1-FY) per line as well that I would like to include on the summary but I imagine I could just repeat whatever process is used to grab the current Value cuts.

I have a list of unique Businesses
businesses = [BA1, BA2, BA3, BA4, BA5]
and a list of unique Business Types
[Widgets, Cups, Snorkels, Bread, Cat Food, Gravel, Rocks, Minerals, Something, Bonbons, Gummy Bears]
and finally a list of the Values
values = [Value-Q1, Value-Q2, Value-Q3, Value-Q4, Value-FY]

and I tried doing a for loop off of the lists

maybe I need to make the dataframe values be on their own individual lines? I tried the following for at least the sum of FY

```
for b in businesses
   for bt in business types
         df_sums = df.loc['Business' == b, 'Business Type' == bt, 'Value-FY'].sum()
```

but it didn't quite give me what I was hoping for

I'm sure there's a better way to at least grab the values (I managed to get FY values per business into a dictionary) for totals but not totals per business per business type (which is also unique per business).

If anyone has any advice or can point me in the right direction I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: Generally I think Excel is a better tool for formatted output. You can probably do what you want in seperate sheet in Excel after putting there raw data table

Comment: Absolutely sumif formulas would do the trick and building them out take very little time, I was just hoping that it's at least vaguely viable to grab data cuts like this for future use in making dashboards or something.

Comment: You certainly can do calculations of the subsums with groupby. But formatted output is a separate trick

Comment: Yeah, I realize that my question is closer to 2-3 questions in one. If I understand the first question though (how to grab the subsums) then I think I can research how to format the output later on! I can try to use group_by to do that, thanks!

Comment: You will get more useful answers if you split your question and ask bit by bit

Comment: Just fixed the original post, thanks! I'll report back if group_by works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to use the group_by method for this. Group_by allows for several grouping options. I have attached a link to the documentation on the method. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html

Comment: This worked for grouping the Business but left me confused on how to group the Business Type and subsequent summary information related to business type. At least with my basic understanding of group_by.

Maybe I need to create separate lists and then create new dataframes based on those lists?